# how to make select in list of objects

Tags: flutter, dart

I´d like filter this list to obtain adress(result should be 'address 002') where name == 'name02'.
How can I achieve this?

And also not sure where is the best place to insert data into list.I only need insert data into list at once, when application starting.

```
class ListOfAdressDb {

  String name;
  String address;
  double locLat;
  double locLng;

 ListOfAdressDb({this.name, this.address, this.locLat, this.locLng});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{ ${this.name}, ${this.address}, ${this.locLat}, ${this.locLng} }';
  }
}

main() {
  List listOfAdress = [];
  listOfAdress.add(ListOfAdressDb(
      name: 'name01',
      address: 'address 001',
      locLat: 11.1111111,
      locLng: 11.1111111));
  
  listOfAdress.add(ListOfAdressDb(
      name: 'name02',
      address: 'address 002',
      locLat: 22.2222222,
      locLng: 22.2222222));      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your List with the where-funtion of List. This function will give you an filtered List like that:

```
var filteredList = listOfAddress.where((ListOfAddressDB entry) => entry.name == 'name02').toList();
```

Comment: it gives me error  [link](https://dartpad.dev/64f8ae9e2767011a5c87ac4af676f6ec)

Comment: then you have to give your List a type like this: List<ListOfAddressDB> listOfAddress = [];

Comment: it gives me error "ListOfAddressDB its not type" [link](https://dartpad.dev/64f8ae9e2767011a5c87ac4af676f6ec)

Comment: Oh sorry my fault just a typo. Try this: List<ListOfAddressDb> listOfAddress = [];

Comment: thanks a lot, now  I have filtered list, but I woud need direct access for key "address"
print(filteredList[2]); or print(filteredList['address']) does not work.

Comment: try filteredList[0].address